# How to move subcaptions in a subfigure environments

Tags: subfloats

I am using the subfigure environment to show 4 figures, 2 in each line. Now, the problem is that the caption of each figure goes over two lines. I want the caption to be written in one line, but at the same time keep the dimensions of my figures small. Here is how I have included my figures:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imgs/first_figure.png}
        \vspace*{.2cm}
        \caption{My first subcaption.}
    \end{subfigure}\hspace*{3cm}
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imgs/second_figure.png}
        \vspace*{.2cm}
        \caption{second subcaption is slightly longer.}
    \end{subfigure} \\\vspace*{.5cm}
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imgs/third_figure.png}
        \vspace*{.2cm}
        \caption{third subcaption is slightly longer.}
    \end{subfigure}\hspace*{3cm}
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imgs/fourth_figure.png}
        \vspace*{.2cm}
        \caption{fourth subcaption is slightly longer.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vspace*{.5cm}
    \caption{Four figures.}
\end{figure}
```

I tried putting an additional `\hspace*{-2cm}` in front of each subcaption, but it litterally had no effect at all. That's strange as the `\vspace*{.2cm}` is doing exactly what I intended. Any suggestions?

Comment: The caption gets its width from the minipage.  Using  negative \hspace won't help.  You would need another minipage or \parbox with a wider width.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 4 subfigures, you can easily use up to `0.5\textwidth` for each.  You just need to shrink the images.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \advance\abovecaptionskip  by 0.2cm
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{My first subcaption.}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{second subcaption is slightly longer.}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{third subcaption is slightly longer.}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{fourth subcaption is slightly longer.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vspace{.3cm}% plus 0.2
    \caption{Four figures.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]